# DELETE on table 'USER' caused a foreign key violation

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, entity, eclipselink

I've a problem when I try to delte a row in a table called "USER" that is in relationship with the table "ADDRESS". In particular, this is part of my User entity class

```
public class User implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
  private String username;
  @Column(unique = true)
  private String email;
  private String password;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Address> addressList;
```

and this is part of my Address entity class

```
public class Address implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
  ...
  private String city;
  @ManyToOne
  private User user;
```

I use an EntityManager to persist my objects and it works very well. But when I try to execute "DELETE FROM USER WHERE USER.ID = 1", for example, my NetBeans IDE returns to me the following error

[Exception, Error code 30.000, SQLState 23503] DELETE on table 'USER' caused a violation on foreign key constraint 'ADRSSUSERID' on the key (1)

So, what's the problem? I tried everything to resolve this problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you have user within the address entity?

Comment: A user can have one or more addresses, that's fine. But why would you reference a user id within the address table? The address table seems to have a foreign key pointing to the users table, which does not make too sense and would ecplain the error.

Comment: Yes, it's because in the address table there is a "owner_id" that is a foreign key for "user_id" in table User.

Comment: Yes Dan, it is modeled in this way because a user can have multiple addresses.

Comment: I was unsure of my answer after this conversation so I removed it, but I'd be interested in hearing a better answer.  It seems like you'd want a delete of the user to Cascade to its addresses.  How would that be done, if there is a many to one relationship between address and user?  The key has to be on the address side, right?

Comment: I try to explain better what I would to do. So, for example, when I delete a User I want that all the addresses associated to him will be deleted. Another example: when I load a user profile from the db, I would to load all his addresses too. These are two examples of what I'm trying to do with this relationship.

Answer (score 0):

If an `address` record has an owner pointing to the `user` table, then user with `id=1` must be an owner for at least 1 `address`, therefore removing the user would make those address records orphan.

You have 2 options to handle the situation:

1. Before deleting a user, you need to verify if it is an owner of any addresses and either deny the deletion if it is or remove the user as the owner of those addresses. I would recommend this option because it gives you the most control over the process.
2. You may define the owner relationship with `on delete cascade` option, which would result in deleting those addresses the given user is owner of when you remove a user. Since you have another relationship between users and addresses, I would not use this solution because deletion of a user may result in a chain deletion of addresses and other users.